# NSlayoutConstraint with swift 1.2 error

Tags: swift, xcode6, nslayoutconstraint

my code used to work in swift 1.1 , but now with 1.2 it is crashing with this error.

> `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: A multiplier of 0 or a nil second item together with a location for the first attribute creates an illegal constraint of a location equal to a constant. Location attributes must be specified in pairs'`

```
 /* Create View with label top header  TABLE */
    let header:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 40))

    var noteBodyLabel = UILabel()
    noteBodyLabel.text = "Aquí te presentamos las últimas tendencias en Alacarta.do"
    noteBodyLabel.numberOfLines = 2
    noteBodyLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
      noteBodyLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    noteBodyLabel.font = UIFont(name:noteBodyLabel.font.fontName, size: 12)
    noteBodyLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)


    var widthCons = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: noteBodyLabel,
        attribute: .Width,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: view.superview,
        attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
        multiplier: 1, constant: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 80)


    let topCons = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: noteBodyLabel,
        attribute: .Top,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: view.superview,
        attribute: .Bottom,
        multiplier: 1, constant: 10);


    /*
    let bottomCons = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: noteBodyLabel,
        attribute: .Bottom,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: ,
        attribute: .Bottom,
        multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
    */
    let leftCons = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: noteBodyLabel,
        attribute: .Left,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: view.superview,
        attribute: .Left,
        multiplier: 1, constant: 40);
    let rightCons = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: noteBodyLabel,
        attribute: .Right,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: view.superview,
        attribute: .Right,
        multiplier: 1, constant: 40);


  header.addSubview(noteBodyLabel)


  noteBodyLabel.addConstraints([topCons,leftCons,rightCons,widthCons])


        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header
```

Comment: Just read the error! It tells you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Your first constraint (width constraint on `noteBodyLabel`) is wrong.....the `toItem` should be nil

```
  var widthCons = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: noteBodyLabel,
        attribute: .Width,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: nil,
        attribute: .NotAnAttribute, // this means to toItem should be nil
        multiplier: 1, constant: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 80)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error warns you:
`A multiplier of 0 or a nil second item together with a location for the first attribute creates an illegal constraint of a location equal to a constant. Location attributes must be specified in pairs'`

A width constraint with `.NotAnAttribute` should not have a `toItem` object. Try `toItem:nil`

Comment: A width constraint CAN have a toItem just not when using ".NotAnAttribute" for the related attribute.

Comment: guys , i appreciate your help so much... i modified settled to nil, but it is still crashing.. if i delete all constraints app doesn't crash.. what needed for is.. adding a view to  HEADER of a UItableview, and centering a label overthere..

Comment: By far, the only constraint that works with the WidthCons , as soon as i uncomment any of the others, im getting the error.. i think it has to do with toItem: view.superview

Comment: contraints won't crash your app, as long as you follow the rules, if it is crashing, you have to debug it or paste the crash logs. But this kind of issues is very easy to fix, because you can add break points to know where goes wrong. For autolayout issue, it's hard to explain in a few words, I think you should first understand how the autolayout works, and then start coding it. Use storyboard or xib to warm you self up about playing with autolayout.

Comment: Thanks wngzero, i just had to add the view tonthe table header usong the storyboard and constraining thru there.. So i got what i needed... Thanks to all for the answers! , my best regards

Comment: if it resloves your problem, consider accept one of the answers